# Separating ASCII text from binary content in a file

Tags: java, file, binary, ascii, extract

I have a file that has both ASCII text and binary content. I would like to extract the text without having to parse the binary content as the binary content is 180MB. Can I simply extract the text for further manipulation ... what would be the best way of going about it.

The ASCII is at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: How are the two sections delimited?

Comment: When I look at a raw file it seems that the first line is ASCII and the rest is binary, so would it be enough to just read the first line. I guess that is probably a quick and dirty solution. What I am wondering is, is there a way to detect that the ASCII code has stopped and the binary code has started?

Comment: Just read the first line, then. It's less heartache and is the correct solution if it's always delimited by a line break.

Comment: What is the file format? A common format could potentially have a framework for extracting that data.

Comment: Its a FITS file - if there is a framework for extracting the data it would be great.

Comment: Also take a look at HTTP request parsing.  The principles are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 libraries to read FITS files in Java [here](http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html):

> **Java**
>
> [nom.tam.fits](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/fits/java/v1.0/) classes
>
> A Java FITS library has been developed which provides efficient -- at least for Java -- I/O for FITS images and binary tables. The Java libraries support all basic FITS formats and gzip compressed files. Support for access to data subsets is included and the HIERARCH convention may be used.
>
> [eap.fits](http://swift.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/swift/sdc/software/java/)
>
> Includes an applet and application for viewing and editing FITS files. Also includes a general purpose package for reading and writing FITS data. It can read PGP encrypted files if the optional PGP jar file is available.
>
> [jfits](http://www.hq.eso.org/%7Epgrosbol/fits_java/jfits.html)
>
> The jfits library supports FITS images and ASCII and binary tables. In-line modification of keywords and data is supported.
>
> [STIL](http://www.star.bristol.ac.uk/%7Embt/stil/)
>
> A pure java general purpose table I/O library which can read and write FITS binary tables amongst other table formats. It is efficient and can provide fast sequential or random read access to FITS tables much larger than physical memory. There is no support for FITS images.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any Java classes that will read the ASCII characters and ignore the rest, but the easiest thing I can come up with here is to use the `strings` utility (assuming you are on a Unix-based system).

> SYNOPSIS
>          strings [ - ] [ -a ] [ -o ] [ -t format ] [ -number ]  [  -n  number  ]
>          [--] [file ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Strings  looks  for  ASCII  strings in a binary file or standard
>   input.
>          Strings is useful for identifying random object files  and 
>   many  other
>          things.   A  string is any sequence of 4 (the default) or more
>   printing
>          characters ending with a newline or a  null.   Unless  the  - 
>   flag  is
>          given,  strings  looks  in  all sections of the object files except
>   the
>          (__TEXT,__text) section.  If no files are specified standard  input 
>   is
>          read.

You could then pipe the output to another file and do whatever you want with it.

**Edit**: with the additional information that all the ASCII comes at the beginning, it would be a little easier to extract the text programmatically; still, this is faster than writing code.

Comment: You will be taking multiple such files as inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can tell where the end of the ASCII content is, just read characters from the file until you find the end of it, and close the file.

Comment: The issue is figuring out how to tell where the end of the ASCII content is

Comment: There isn't an easy way. The best you can do is stop when you encounter the first non-printable character (because you know that's not going to be in the ASCII section), but then you're still likely to pick up some garbage from the start of the binary section before that. It would be best if you knew the exact structure of the binary section - say, if it always started with the same character sequence. Then you could look for that to determine where the ASCII section ends.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that there is some token which divides the file into the binary and ASCII components (say, "#END#" on a line all by itself), you can do sometihng like the following:

```
import java.io.*;

// ...

public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("object.bin");
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(f);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d));

    String s = "";
    while ((s = b.readLine()) != "#END#") {
      // ASCII contents parsed here.
      System.out.println(s);
    }

    d.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("kablammo! " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: € Seems to be the first character very often, perhaps I could use that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a method that checks whether a particular character meets your criteria (here, I've covered characters that are found on the keyboard). Once you hit a character for which the method returns false, you know you've hit the binary. Note that valid ASCII characters may also form part of the binary so you may end up with a few extra characters at the end.

```
static boolean isAsciiCharacter(char c) {
    return (c >= ' ' && c <= '~') ||
            c == '\n' ||
            c == '\r';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first 2880 bytes of a [FITS file](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/fits_overview.html) are ASCII header data, representing 36 80-column
"card images".  There are no line terminator characters, just a 36x80 ASCII array, padded out with blanks if necessary.  There may be additional 2880-byte ASCII headers preceding the binary data; you'd have to parse the first set of headers to know how much ASCII to expect.

But I heartily endorse Oscar Reyes' advice to use an existing package to decode FITS files!  Two of the packages he mentioned are hosted by NASA's Goddard Space Flight Center, who are also responsible for maintaining the FITS format. That's about as definitive a source as you can get.